# symfony form builder update option field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

is it possible to update an option field after adding it ?

```
$builder
    ->add('examens', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'TelegrammeExamenBundle:ExamExamen',
        'property'  => 'libelle',
        'required'    => true,
        'empty_value' => 'Sélectionnez un examen',
        //'data' => $this->em->getReference("TelegrammeExamenBundle:ExamExamen", 510),
        'data' => null,
        'query_builder' => function(ExamenRepository $r) {
            return $r->getSelectList();
        },
        'attr' => array('class' => 'bg_white_filet_gris')
    ))
;
```

how modify field option ??? (setOption don't exist)

```
if (...) $builder->get('examens')->setOption('property', 'test');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply `->add()` it again. As the API documentation suggests for the `add` method: 
*Adds or replaces a child to the form*

http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_add

This can be used to modify form elements for example in a `FormEvent`.

---

***Alternatively*** the `FormBuilder` provides a `setAttribute()` method which can be used as follows:

```
$builder->get('examens')->setAttribute('property', 'test');
```

Comment: Added another method to my answer. Please note that *from inside* a `FormEvent` you can not use this latter method: you need to re-add the form again as defined in the former method (as you don't have the builder available there)

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás `$builder->get('examens')` returns `FormBuilder`, not the field. So, it sets the form attribute, not the field attribute. I could not achieve it.

Comment: @Stihu You are right it returns a `FormBuilder`, an instance FOR that specific field. And the `setAttribute` should be then applied to that form field. You could not achieve what?

Comment: OK since 2.8 version

Comment: `setAttribute()` does not modify an `options`, it modifies `attributes`.

Comment: how to modify `placeholder` option? using setAttribute not working